# Find the correct value from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

so my problem is the following:

I've been trying to match different values to their pairs on a different sheet.
A scanner writes different values. For example: Apple1, Apple2, Apple3, etc.

All of these values have a pair No. (1, 2, 3, etc), which has to return 0 / 1 depending on the version of the written value.

What I want is:

Check a column, and find the pair of each cell from another sheet.
After it's been found, copy-paste the data from that row.

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. At least you should provide some sample data and your expected output. Did you try formulas - sounds like `INDEX/MATCH` could help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code does not match your question, you just loop, but there is nothing trying to match data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I'm trying to improve my questions in the future. I'm new to SO, so all suggesttions are welcomed.
Also, I edited the question, now I see what were wrong, hopefully it's more clear now.